# Can some one help me to conver it into LINQ i m using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

select  ForumCategories.ID ,  ForumCategories.Title , ForumCategories.DateCreated,
CO = ( select COUNT(*) from ForumSubCategories where ForumSubCategories.CategoryID_FK = ForumCategories.ID)
from ForumCategories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var q = from fc in Context.ForumCategories
        select new 
        {
            Id = fc.ID,
            Title = fc.Title,
            DateCreated = fc.DateCreated
            CO = fc.ForumSubCategories.Count()
        };
return q;
```

The "join" (subquery) is implicit; it's defined in the relationship between `ForumCategories` and `ForumSubCategories` in your model. Using this syntax, the call to `Count()` will be done on the DB server.

Comment: and what if i have to pass this result as data source to gridview control

Comment: q is `IEnumerable`, which should be enough. But you can project onto a strong type if you need `IEnumerable<SomeViewModel>` http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/12/31/38500/

Comment: Craig what if i want to get the dateCreated from ForumSubCategories how can i do that.

Comment: "The" `dateCreated`? Aren't there lots of them (since there are lots of ForumSubCategories; otherwise you wouldn't be counting them)? Do you want a list of all the dates? The maximum?

Comment: sorry Craig i wasnt able to explain it well. i got three tables ForumCategories (ID, Title, Desc, DateCreated) , ForumSubCategories ID, Title, Desc, DateCreated, CategoryID_FK) and ForumPosts ( ID, Heading, Detail, DateCreated, SubCategoryID_FK).  now i want to return FourmCtegories.ID, FourmCtegories.Title , Count of SubCategories and LastPost posted uneder that Category. thanks